# Keys.onPressed on TableView called twice

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I've found some strange behavior when working with `TableView`. Let's suppose we have the following code:

```
TableView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    TableViewColumn { title: "column1"; role: "col1" }
    TableViewColumn { title: "column2"; role: "col2" }
    TableViewColumn { title: "column3"; role: "col3" }
    model: ListModel {
        ListElement { col1: "value1"; col2: "value2"; col3: "value3" }
        ListElement { col1: "value4"; col2: "value5"; col3: "value6" }
        ListElement { col1: "value7"; col2: "value8"; col3: "value9" }
    }
    Keys.onPressed: {
        if(event.isAutoRepeat)
            return;
        if(event.key === Qt.Key_Space) {
            console.log("Space pressed");
            //event.accepted = true;
        }
    }
}
```

and the output I get is:

> qml: Space pressed
>
> qml: Space pressed

It means that `Keys.onPressed` for some reason is called twice. If I set `event.accepted` to `true` it works as expected but sometimes I just want to check pressed buttons without accepting them. For example, if Up arrow is pressed I don't want to accept it. In this case the handler is called twice.

Comment: Maybe a quirk of the tableView implementation (items stacked on each other) ? Anyway it shouldn't break your code even if you don't accept you can just ignore it twice ...?

Comment: I'm not sure whether to post as a comment or an answer, as it looks like you've [already created a bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51160) and it was accepted, so it's most likely a valid bug in Qt.

Comment: Yes, it could be a bug. Thanks @Mitch for commenting that. I think currently I have to use workaround with accepting the event

Answer (score -1):

It works correctly if you put your Keys.onPressed code outside of TableView scope, looks like a Qt bug...